# MongoDB sharding problems

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Our mongodb server deployed with 2 shards, each has 1 master server and 2 slave servers. 
The four slave servers run mongo config as proxy, and two of the slave servers run arbiters.
But the mongodb coundn't be used now.

I can connect to 192.168.0.1:8000(mongos) and exec queries like 'use database' or 'show dbs', but i cann't exec queries in a choosed database such as 'db.foo.count()', 'db.foo.findOne()'

Here is the error log:

```
mongos> db.dev.count()
Fri Aug 16 12:55:36 uncaught exception: count failed: {
    "assertion" : "DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 10.81.4.72:7100 query: { setShardVersion: \"\", init: true, configdb: \"10.81.4.72:7300,10.42.50.26:7300,10.81.51.235:7300\", serverID: ObjectId('520db0a51fa00999772612b9'), authoritative: true }",
    "assertionCode" : 10276,
    "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
    "ok" : 0
}




Fri Aug 16 11:23:29 [conn8431] DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Fri Aug 16 11:23:29 [conn8430] Socket recv() errno:104 Connection reset by peer 10.81.4.72:7100
Fri Aug 16 11:23:29 [conn8430] SocketException: remote: 10.81.4.72:7100 error: 9001 socket exception [1] server [10.81.4.72:7100] 
Fri Aug 16 11:23:29 [conn8430] DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Fri Aug 16 11:23:29 [conn8430] DBException in process: could not initialize cursor across all shards because : DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 10.81.4.72:7100 query: { setShardVersion: "", init: true, configdb: "10.81.4.72:7300,10.42.50.26:7300,10.81.51.235:7300", serverID: ObjectId('520d99c972581e6a124d0561'), authoritative: true } @ s01/10.36.31.36:7100,10.42.50.24:7100,10.81.4.72:7100
```

i can only start on mongos, queries wouldn't be exec if more than 1 mongos run at the same time, error log:

```
mongos> db.dev.count() Fri Aug 16 15:12:29 uncaught exception: count failed: { "assertion" : "DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 10.81.4.72:7100 query: { setShardVersion: \"\", init: true, configdb: \"10.81.4.72:7300,10.42.50.26:7300,10.81.51.235:7300\", serverID: ObjectId('520dd04967557902f73a9fba'), authoritative: true }", "assertionCode" : 10276, "errmsg" : "db assertion failure", "ok" : 0 }
```

Comment: did it work before? did you change anything in the configuration? How did you set-up your replica-sets?

Comment: From the server that is running mongos, can you try connecting to each of the mongods (configs and masters) directly via the mongo shell as a first test? Also, why are you using a Master/Slave configuration over Replica Sets?

Comment: i can only start on mongos, queries wouldn't be exec if more than 1 mongos run at the same time, error log:  mongos> db.dev.count()
Fri Aug 16 15:12:29 uncaught exception: count failed: {
 "assertion" : "DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 10.81.4.72:7100 query: { setShardVersion: \"\", init: true, configdb: \"10.81.4.72:7300,10.42.50.26:7300,10.81.51.235:7300\", serverID: ObjectId('520dd04967557902f73a9fba'), authoritative: true }",
 "assertionCode" : 10276,
 "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
 "ok" : 0
}

Comment: It is basically saying one of your shards is acting up and one of your comments: "it works well before and be like this since a server crashed and reboot" makes me suspecious, have you checked for corruption on that shard? Have you tried replaying the journal? Have you checked the servers own hardware is ok?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify if your set-up was working before, if you are just setting it up now?

To repair your MongoDB, you might want to follow this link:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/

**References**

[MongoDB Documentation : Deploying a Shard-Cluster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/)

[MongoDB Documentation : Add Shards to an existing cluster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-shards-to-shard-cluster/)

Older, outdated(!) info:

[YouTube Video on Setting-up Sharding for MongoDB](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKG_M5UQE9w)

[Corresponding Blog on blog.serverdensity.com](http://blog.serverdensity.com/automating-partitioning-sharding-and-failover-with-mongodb/)

Comment: it works well before and be like this since a server crashed and reboot

Comment: @feiyan have you checked for corruption?